# Stacking up rows from tow tables using mysql select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables and wish to join them together so I can query them together. Is there anyway that I can achieve this?

For illustration purpose, see the figures below.

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTdkW.png)

PLEASE NOTE THAT time_enrolled FOLLOWS THE PATTERN ON BOTH TABLES

Comment: Hint: In order to join two tables together, you need one of the tables to have a foreign key of the other table, then you can run a query and `join` them together on `foreign.key = primary.key`

Comment: @PaulKaram : i think OP wants union/union all rather join

Comment: @Prabhat G I didn't see the picture at first, and read that he wants to join. After all, glad you helped him :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
Select
id,name,age,time_enrolled,date_joined, null as occupation from students
union
select
id,name,null as age,time_enrolled,null as date_joined, occupation
from parents
```

Comment: Why not `UNION ALL` instead?

Comment: @jarlh  AFAIK, union all causes duplicates(if any). Will `union all` work better than `union` here ?

Comment: `UNION ALL` simply takes one result set and adds another - without removing duplicates (if any.) `UNION` removes duplicates - which is an extra cost if not needed - as here. (UNION is actually the short form of `UNION DISTINCT`.)

Comment: With the two selects MYSQL gives an error. Can you edit it please? Here is the error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select
id,name,age,time_enrolled,date_joined, null as occupation from students
u' at line 1

Comment: Thank you @PrabhatG Your answer does it for me.